# postgresql syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I trying to create this update statement that adds the average runtimes from today into a temporary table. I keep getting the following syntax error:

> ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "INNER"   Position: 22
>
> Query
>   = UPDATE temptbl1 AS T INNER JOIN ( select jobno, avg(elaptime) as avgrun
>   from cmr_runinf where
>   to_timestamp(timestmp,
>   'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') > (now() -
>   interval '1 DAY') GROUP BY JOBNO ) AS
>   source ON T.jobno = source.jobno SET
>   T.todayrun
>   = source.avgrun

My statement:

```
UPDATE temptbl1 AS T
INNER JOIN
(
select jobno, avg(elaptime) as avgrun
from cmr_runinf
where to_timestamp(timestmp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') > (now() - interval '1 DAY')
GROUP BY JOBNO
) AS source
ON T.jobno = source.jobno
SET T.todayrun = source.avgrun
```

Answer (score 1):

The SET clause should come after the UPDATE clause.  Also you probably want a FROM clause in there somewhere.

```
UPDATE temptbl1 AS T1 
SET T1.todayrun = source.avgrun 
FROM ( 
    SELECT jobno, avg(elaptime) as avgrun 
      FROM cmr_runinf 
     WHERE to_timestamp(timestmp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') 
           > (now() - interval '1 DAY')
    GROUP BY jobno
) AS source
WHERE T1.jobno = source.jobno
```

Also see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html

Comment: Okay, I changed my query around. but now I am getting a different error... 

ERROR: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry in subquery for table
"source"
  Position: 203

Query = UPDATE temptbl1 AS T1
SET
T1.todayrun = source.avgrun
FROM (
select jobno, avg(elaptime)
as avgrun
from cmr_runinf
where to_timestamp(timestmp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
> (now() - interval '1 DAY')
GROUP BY SOURCE.JOBNO
)
AS source
Where T1.jobno = source.jobno

Comment: ') AS source' needs to come before 'GROUP BY SOURCE.JOBNO

Comment: Why do you link to such an old version of the Postgres manual? I would recommend to use "current" instead of the version number in the URL

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE temptbl1 AS T1 
SET T1.todayrun = source.avgrun 
FROM ( select jobno
            , avg(elaptime) as avgrun 
       from cmr_runinf 
       where to_timestamp(timestmp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
                > (now() - interval '1 DAY')
       GROUP BY jobno     <-- not source.jobno, there is no source inside parenthesis
     ) AS source
WHERE T1.jobno = source.jobno
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it, it's trying to perform the update on a virtual table (join of two physical tables), which isn't permitted.

The SET needs to come after the update